# Pygame text is overlapping

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm making a game that picks a random number and you have to guess what it is, but, When ever it say's you win or you lose the text just stays there and I can't figure out how to delete to old text. I have tried to do screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) but it doesn't change a thing. (Yes, I did do pygame.display.flip()) I have looked all over the web (I checked stack overflow first) but to no success. HELP!

```
import random, pygame, pygbutton
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
dice = random.randint(1, 6)

def window():
    width = 600
    height = 600
    # background_color = (0, 0, 0)
    WH = (width, height)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WH)
    background = pygame.image.load("wood.jpg").convert()
    background=pygame.transform.scale(background,(600, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Dice Game!")
    screen.blit(background, (600, 600))
    num1_button = pygbutton.PygButton((0, 0, 100,50), '1')
    num2_button = pygbutton.PygButton((0, 50, 100, 50), '2')
    # screen.fill(background_color)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)

    running = True
    while running == True:
        dice = random.randint(1, 6)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quit()
            if 'click' in num1_button.handleEvent(event):
                if dice == 1:
                    text = font.render("You Win!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                    background.blit(text, (155, 255))
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                else:
                    Text = font.render("You Lose!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                    background.blit(Text, (155, 255))
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                cliq = True
            if 'click' in num2_button.handleEvent(event):
                if dice == 2:
                    text = font.render("You Win!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                    background.blit(text, (155, 255))
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                else:
                    Text = font.render("You Lose!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                    background.blit(Text, (155, 255))
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
                cliq=True

        num1_button.draw(screen)
        num2_button.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()   


window()
```

I would also like it if you told me where to put the changes. THANK YOU in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are blitting the text to the background surface. This text sticks around until you reload the surface. Reloading the surface is a bad idea. It will take a lot of cpu power that you don't need to spend. Instead, just blit the text directly to the screen.

```
        if 'click' in num1_button.handleEvent(event):
            if dice == 1:
                text = font.render("You Win!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
                screen.blit(text, (155, 255))
```